# How to stop disabled Google Assistant popping up on home button long presses?

Tags: google-assistant, home-button

I don't use Google Assistant, so I disabled it, by (1) opening the Google app, then (2) going to settings from the profile icon, then (3) choosing "Google Assistant" settings, then (4) scrolling a long way down to "General" settings, then (5) toggling off the top toggle that simply says "Google Assistant".

However, sometimes the device thinks I long-pressed the home button (e.g. if I swipe up too slowly) and pops up a Google Assistant nag screen asking me to re-enable it.

[image: Popup saying 'Your Google Assistant is ready to help you get things done', with a 'Turn on' button]

How do I stop the Home button from doing this? There don't seem to be any related settings in the Google app settings.

I've found dozens and dozens of articles explaining how to disable Google Assistant - which I've already done - but not how to stop this home button behaviour.

Device is a Samsung S22 Ultra running Android 14 and OneUI 6.0 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Eventually I found something, at the end of [this article](https://www.nextpit.com/how-to-deactivate-google-assistant). This home button behaviour is apparently a system behaviour in general Android settings outside of Google Assistant, set to summon whatever is your current "Digital Assistant App" - and by default, Google Assistant remains the default Assistant App, even if disabled.

So, you need to **find your default Assistant App setting,  and set it to "none"**:

1. Pull down from the top, open **system settings** (cog icon)
2. Go to "**Choose Defaults Apps**" (under "Apps" in the main settings list, or,  search for it)
3. Go to "**Digital Assistant Apps**"
4. Tap on the *text* that says "**Device Assistant App**" with "Google" under it (not the cog icon next to it)

   [image]
5. Choose "**None**" from the list

After this, long presses on the home button should do nothing and pop nothing up.

---

*Disclaimer: as always with Android,  labels,  menu positions, behaviour and side effects may vary between devices and versions, this is only tested on a Samsung S22 Ultra running Android 14 and OneUI 6.0*